# Set method parameters as readonly

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, readonly

How can I create a method that has a readonly object parameter?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
}

public void RunMe(Person p)
{
    p.Name = "XXXX";
}

var p = new Person();
p.Name = "YYYY";
RunMe(p);
Console.WriteLine(p.Name); // "XXXX"
```

The above code results in the person's name being "XXXX". I want to prevent the `RunMe` method from changing the person's properties.

Comment: you can make it struct.

Answer (score 10):

You can use interfaces to restrict the access. It is also better to pass interfaces instead of concrete objects as parameters to methods.

```
public interface IReadablePerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IWritablePerson
{
    string Name { set; }
}

public class Person : IReadablePerson, IWritablePerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then have a method like this:

```
public void RunMe(IReadablePerson p)
{
   p.Name = "XXXX"; //compile time error!!!
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty decent solution indeed, +1

Comment: @Jcl It is a good alternative to my answer, and depending on the system may be the way to go, but using lots of interfaces can complicate things so you need to use some judgment as to whether it's worth that effort + complexity.

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this is via the `get` and `set` accessors, just don't define a set:

```
public String Name { get; }
```

This will make a property that you can treat exactly like a normal field for your purposes. Underneath properties are a little more complex using methods to set a backing field which you can read about on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/w86s7x04.aspx)

If you need to be able to set the property just once then define the `set` as private and pass the parameter into the constructor:

```
public class Person
{
  public Person(String name)
  {
     this.Name = name;
  }

  public String Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: But that wouldn't allow him to do `p.name="YYYY";` as he is expecting. If I understood the question, he wants a method (not in the class) not to change the original object passed in, not protecting the property or field everywhere

Comment: Than he cant set value

Comment: @GrantWinney If property set is private he can't set from RunMe method

Comment: @GrantWinney: You're right, it is a little unclear but I took the same interpretation as your comment.

Comment: @Ian I understood what I understood because of the title of the question "Set method parameters as readonly", which mixed with the body (where there's only one method), would make me think what I thought... but yes, the question definitely lacks expressiveness and could be understood in many different ways :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to somehow be able to lock the member.  One option would be to make the "set" dependent on another member like this:

```
public class Name
{
    public bool Locked { get; set; }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            if(!this.Locked)
                this.name = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:  Alternate method for making lock permanent.

```
public class Person
{
    private bool locked = false;
    public void Lock()
    {
        this.locked = true;
    }
    public bool Locked
    {
        get { return this.locked; }
    }
    // add same Name member as above
}
```

Edit:  Yet ANOTHER way to lock, using a key.

```
private object key = null;

public bool Locked
{ get { return this.key != null; } }

public void Lock(object obj)
{
    if (this.key == null)
    {
        this.key = obj;
    }
}

public void Unlock(object obj)
{
    if (this.key == obj)
    {
        this.key = null;
    }
}
```

You can throw an exception if you want if trying to unlock with the wrong key object.

Comment: a method can simply set `Locked` to false and set `Name` value.

Comment: If that isn't desirable, simply make Lock a method that sets a private member "locked" to true.

Comment: how we can unlock it then?

Comment: I'm confused.  Either the member can be unlocked or not, you can't have both.

Comment: assume you create an object `obj`, you want to manipulate it, pass it to a method as readonly and then manipulate it again. how can you do this?

Comment: Make a copy and lock the copy before sending it out?

Comment: what if your object is a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour described after the first setting of the property is this:

```
private string _name;
public string Name 
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { // no setting }
}
```

This is NOT A GOOD PRACTICE.
you create unexpected behaviour for properties (if this is a public class).
Any consuming assembly cannot view the body of the get and set methods would expect a set method to behave a sertain way (setting a value).

This kind of behaviour should be put in a seperate set method. 
This way you can see if it changed, throw an exception if you want, or return true if it changed. 
Then you can still use the property for getting the value.

```
private bool _locked;
public string Name { get; private set;}
public boolSetName(string value)
{
    bool hasChanged = false;
    if(!_locked)
    {
        Name = value;
        _locked = true;
        hasChanged = true;
    }
    return hasChanged
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this creates any unexpected behaviour. It doesn't make sense (since having a setter accessor that does nothing doesn't make sense), but it's not unexpected. Also, this wouldn't just do "EXACTLY" what the OP wants, since he doesn't want the value to be changed on the method (as per the question title), but would still need the other `p.Name="YYYY";` to change the name. This wouldn't change it at all, anywhere, and it'd print nothing at all (instead of the name it was assigned before calling the `RunMe` method)

Comment: @Jcl This is unexpected behaviour for any consumer of the class, since it is a set property which does not set anything. This is is more clear when the assembly in which the person class resides is not editable for the consumer.

Comment: if you want to define it that way, then any property setter that mutates the state of any object (other than setting its backing field) would be "unexpected behavior"... all these non-standard things are (or should be) usually documented, so as not to make them "unexpected". Yes, I know what you mean, but I would definitely not define it with that wording.

Comment: My mistake on the `p.Name="YYYY"` part.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in C# are reference types, so there's no way to do what you want to do if `Person` is a `class`.

You could make it a value type (by making it a `struct`) in which case, a copy of the object would be passed in, but that may take implications at some other points in your program, so be wary if you do it.

Comment: I think the other answers show that there are ways to get the desired behavior.

Comment: @mfluehr not as I understood the question (and basically the other answers prove it, either by changing the class -not the method-, or passing a different type). I explained that [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719107/set-method-parameters-as-readonly/28719164#comment45725771_28719197) .